# Blog Archive Django

Tags: django, date, blogs, archive

I am trying to follow the [tutorial here](http://www.quxisto.com/2012/mar/5/not-another-django-blog-part-2/) to create a year/month based blog archive. When trying to visit a url like: 'www.example.com/blog/2013/feb' or 'www.example.com/blog/2013', I get a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` using the above method.

I dont really care if the method used is the same as in the tutorial sited above, I just want the archives to work so that if a user visits: 'example.com/blog/2013/' it gives a list of objects created in 2013. Here is what I have so far:

views:

```
from django.views.generic import date_based

def post_archive_year(request, year):
    return date_based.archive_year(
        request,
        year=year,
        date_field='date',
        queryset=Blog.objects.date(),
    )

def post_archive_month(request, year, month):
    return date_based.archive_month(
        request,
        year=year,
        month=month,
        date_field='date',
        queryset=Blog.objects.date(),
    )
```

model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    article = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('blog_detail', None, {
            'year': self.date.year,
            'month': self.date.strftime('%b').lower(),
            'slug': self.slug
        })
```

urls:

```
url(r'^blog/(?P<year>\d{4})/$', view='post_archive_year', name='post_archive_year'),
url(r'^blog/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$', view='post_archive_month', name='post_archive_month'),
```

Thanks for any ideas that can help me create a date-based archive. I appreciate your input.

Comment: `Blog.objects.date()` looks wrong, what are you trying to do here?  I think you want `Blog.objects.all()` or similar...

Comment: Because you absolute url required year, month and slug which your current url only defined year value

Comment: Thanks for your idea @mVChr, but trying `Blog.objects.all()` also results in the same `TypeError`. I was trying `Blog.objects.date()` because that follows the pattern described here (my model field is called 'date' and his is called 'published'): http://www.quxisto.com/2012/mar/7/a-typical-date-based-archive/

Comment: Thanks for your comment @catherine. I haven't used `get_absolute_url` in the template that has an error, however, so I dont think this is the source of my `TypeError`. Do you have any other ideas that I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

The `__unicode__` method needs to return a unicode object.

You are returning `self.name` which is a `CharField`. Only string or buffer-protocol objects can be automatically converted to a unicode object.

Try this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.name
```

Another option for built-in Python types, or any user-defined class that has its own `__unicode__` method:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.name)
```